# Optional percent in Rexeg for URL rewriting

Tags: regex, url, nginx, rewriting

I'm using nginx for an API et my rewriting is in the Vhost and I have an issue with a regex.

My url can be :

- /products/BR3TMVZ9PNWZ/
- /products/BR3TMVZ9PNWZ%BPMMFJDVP9NF/
- /products/BR3TMVZ9PNWZ%BPMMFJDVP9NF%BPNSJSZCRPPF/

The first one works with this :

`rewrite /products/([A-Z0-9]+)/ /products.php?ids=$1 last;`

I tried a lot of thing with % but I already have a HTTP 400

Thank you

Comment: What behaviour do you try to implement?

Comment: the string after /products/ will be send to another API that accept only this format

Comment: @Alex you want to capture complete string following products or string just before %

Comment: @laughing buddha : the complete string

Comment: @Alex if what you want is the complete string, did you try adding `%` inside the brackets? `([A-Z0-9%]+)`

Answer (score 0):

Edit :

`rewrite "^/products/([A-Z0-9]+)\%{0,1}.*$" /products.php?ids=$1 last;`

Should always match the first id `BR3TMVZ9PNWZ`

Comment: Thanks but It's not working, still have an error 400

Comment: Strange "nginx: [emerg] directive "rewrite" is not terminated by ";" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:74" but ; is at the end of the line ...

Comment: You need to enclose the `^/products/([A-Z0-9]+)\%{0,1}.*$` in `"` to avoid nginx for closing the configuration section because of the `}` ;) . Edited

Comment: 400 Bad Request :(

Comment: @Alex Does the URL which pass through the rewrite is really the same as the one you posted? Or has it been escaped like : `/products/BR3TMVZ9PNWZ%25BPMMFJDVP9NF/` ? In this case; the regex would be : `^/products/([A-Z0-9]+)(\%25){0,1}.*$`

Comment: 400 Bad Request too :(